# Defining intersection of two surfaces

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, tangent-line, intersection-theory

I am having a bit of trouble beginning this question.

The question is as follows:

---

Let $r$ be the curve which is the intersection of the surface $z = \frac{1}{3}x^2 + \frac{2}{3}y^2$ and the surface: $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 3$.

Find the equation of the tangent line to the curve $r$ at $\overrightarrow{r_0} = (1, 1, 1)$, and the equation of the plane which is perpendicular to the tangent line at $\overrightarrow{r_0}$.

---

I think I understand how to approach the second part of the problem, but I'm not too sure how to parameterize the intersection $r$.

I've tried substituting $z$ from the first surface in to the second surface:

$$x^2 + y^2 + \left(\frac{1}{3}x^2 + \frac{2}{3}y^2\right)^2 = 3\\
x^2 + y^2 + \frac{1}{9}x^4 + \frac{4}{9}x^2 y^2 + \frac{4}{9}y^4 = 3$$

Let $X = x^2$ and $Y = y^2$,

$$X + Y + \frac{1}{9}X^2 + \frac{4}{9}XY + \frac{4}{9}Y^2 = 3$$

I tried to eliminate the $XY$ but then the whole thing just became a mess with imaginary numbers. How should I proceed? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

I would not try to parameterize the curve, which is the intersection of an elliptic paraboloid and a sphere. Spherical or cylindrical coordinates will not work so well.

I would rather consider the normal vectors to both surfaces (gradient) and use the fact that the tangent vector is orthogonal to both.

> Direction of the tangent vector, $(\frac23,\frac43,-1)\times(2,2,2)$.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's such a creative approach.